# Adding multiple data attributes to one node

Tags: c++, nodes, singly-linked-list

I need a way to add more than one data ( such as name, id, age) into a single node in a linked list in C++. Instead of having the data value being only a name or a number.

Comment: `std::list<my_custom_type>` where `my_custom_type` can have any members you like

Comment: You want a `class` or a `struct`. Look up for those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wish to group your data, there are many ways to do that.
The easiest is if you create a stucture:

```
struct MyData {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

MyData data;
data.id = 1;
data.name = "John";
data.age = 23;

std::list<MyData> list;
list.push_back(data);

...

std::list<MyData>::const_iterator itr = list.begin();
int age = itr->age;
```

Would that help?

Comment: Yes it worked very well, I used a class instead of a struct and had to overload certain operators. But thanks for the main idea.